# The Boolean lattice of a Boolean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, boolean-ring

I am proving that a Boolean Ring is also a Boolean Lattice.

I defined $\leq$ as $x\leq y$ when $xy=x$. The supremum is $a+b+ab$, and infimum is $ab$. The Max element is $1$, Min is $0$.

I proved that $\leq$ is an order relation ($x\leq x, (x\leq y \text{ and } y\leq x) \implies x=y, (x\leq y \text{ and } y\leq z) \implies x\leq z$). I proved that $(S, \leq)$ is a lattice, finding supremum and infimum, then I proved that $(S, \leq)$ is bounded (I found min and max).

Now i need to proved that $(S, \leq)$ is distributive, how do I do it? I'm stuck at this last point.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us how you did define $p$. Then, what form do least upper bound and greatest lower bound take (and in fact, you can define these directly from the ring operations). Then use these forms to prove distributivity.

Comment: i defined p as xpy such us that xy=x. Upper is a+b+ab, lower is ab. Max is 1, Min is 0

Comment: Ok, you're in the right path. By the way, you can also define $x'=1+x$, but I don't think you need that to prove distributivity.

Comment: @ShishRobot Edit your definitions into the post, don't just leave them in the comments.  Using TeX here takes almost no effort at all: see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Given the work you've done so far, the last bit is just computation, right?

Comment: One doesn't say "a boolean ring is a boolean lattice," because that doesn't make sense.  The axioms defining both are incomparable. It is true that a boolean ring gives rise to a boolean lattice and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $x \vee y = x + y + xy$, and $x \wedge y = xy$,

\begin{align}
a \wedge (b \vee c)
&= a \cdot (b + c + bc)\\
&= ab + ac + abc\\
&= ab + ac + (ab)(ac)\\
&= (a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c).
\end{align}